# When to use type inference in typescript and when not to use it when writing types for for a react context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-state

I would like to do what is the "correct"  way to type a `React state` and `set state` inside a custom `context` store. I'm find myself typing my state in two different formats.

##### First format

```
type TSubThemaLaagFeature = IOmgevingscheckSubThemaLaagFeature | null;

interface ISubThemaLaagContext {
  subThemaLaagFeature: TSubThemaLaagFeature;
  setSubThemaLaagFeature: (subThemaLaagFeature: TSubThemaLaagFeature) => void;
}

// ...omitted code


// in my store I use it like this

const useStore = () => {
  const [subThemaLaagFeature, setSubThemaLaagFeature] = useState<
    ISubThemaLaagContext['subThemaLaagFeature']
>(initialContext.subThemaLaagFeature);

/// ...omitted code
}
```

Here `typescript` correctly infers that `setSubThemaLaagFeature` is of type

```
const setSubThemaLaagFeature: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TSubThemaLaagFeature>>
```

But lately I've been wanting to write them like this (second format below) because I find them easier to reason about, I might be doing extra work for nothing though?

##### Second format

```
type TSubThemaLaagState = IOmgevingscheckSubThemaLaagFeature | null;
type TSubThemaLaagAction = React.Dispatch<
  React.SetStateAction<TSubThemaLaagState>
>;

interface ISubThemaLaagContext {
  subThemaLaagFeature: TSubThemaLaagState;
  setSubThemaLaagFeature: (subThemaLaagFeature: TSubThemaLaagState) => void;
}

// ...omitted code


// in my store I use it like this

const useStore = () => {
  const [subThemaLaagFeature, setSubThemaLaagFeature]: [TSubThemaLaagState, TSubThemaLaagAction] = useState<TSubThemaLaagState
>(initialContext.subThemaLaagFeature);

  // ...omitted code
}
```

but when I hover over the `TSubThemaLaagAction` I get the following

```
type TBufferGeometrieAction = (value: React.SetStateAction<TBufferGeometrieState>) => void
```

I would like to know which way is the better way to type a `React.state` and set state action.

Comment: Please go with the first. The second is just more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I've never seen it done the second format, and I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do with that either. You're trying to explicitly set the types of the destructured elements?

For example, my understanding is that, `useState` already infers the type of `setA`, based both on the input parameter `new A()` or (if provided) the class symbol provided in the generic `<A>`.

```tsx
const [a, setA] = useState<A>(new A());
// React can infer the type of setA as React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<A>> 
// without being explicitly set
```

And what you're doing is:

```tsx
type B = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<A>>;
const [a, setA]: [A, B] = useState<A>(new A());
```

But unless you're going to change the type of `setA`, you're really just doing extra work. I mean, there's nothing "incorrect" about what you're doing, but also why write more code? In my opinion, what you're doing seems more confusing.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: honestly I'm just trying to correctly type my useState and I didn't how far I should go, but then ok. Then format #1 it is, and I let typescript infer `setState`.  Thanks

Comment: @intercoder sorry, if I came off snarky, I was just genuinely asking, but I think in this instance, you can rely on React to handle inferring its own typing properly because `useState` is already typed in React's source as `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction>`. There's no need for you to type it.

Comment: Hey @Thomas Yamakaitis, you did come a bit snark at first :) , but no worries man, the information passed through regardless and you  did help me understand a bit more about type inference and type declaration :)